# AEM Package Manager OOTB to filter properties of package filter nodes

Tags: aem, crx

Is there any OOTB solution to filter some properties like `cq:lastReplicated`, `cq:lastReplicatedBy` , etc, I wanted to migrate some code from lower environments to higher these properties shows the newly moved content in author also as replicated especially on sites content. So planning to create the packages with the filters without these properties.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such possibility at the moment. I would suggest to use groovy script (https://github.com/OlsonDigital/cq-groovy-console) to remove not needed properties.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned that there is no such functionality yet. You can either use groovy console or other alternatives as mentioned above or you can unzip your package and use text manipulation to clean the content.xml files to remove the properties. I am sure that some simple XSL or command line should be sufficient to do this.

Package manager is a node level tool so nothing is available to filter properties yet.